# SwiftSocket communication delay

Tags: java, swift, sockets, tcp

I am porting an Android application to iOS platform. This is a app that uses TCP socket programming to communicate with an external ESP8266 device. To debug code I wrote a code in Java using IntelliJ IDE to act as server and Xcode simulator is acting as the server.

```
try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        System.out.println(serverSocket.getInetAddress());
        Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client Accepted");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Got: " +bufferedReader.readLine());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is the code for Server using Java.

```
switch client.connect(timeout: 10) {
    case .success:
        toggleSwitch.isEnabled=true
        connectBtn.isEnabled=false
        upArrow.isEnabled=true
        downArrow.isEnabled=true

    default:
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Connection Failed.", message: "SST Device is not available", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .`default`, handler: { _ in
            NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occured.")
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Above is the part where iOS device connect with the server.

```
resistanceValueInt-=1
let x=client.send(string:"\(-1)")
```

this is where the client sends data to the server. resistanceValueInt is starting at 0 when the app loads. And increment in each button press.

My question is connection with server established immediately. Though the increments and decrements to the values using buttons won't show up immediately. Simulator needs to quit in order to show the result in the Server Console.

Why simulator needs to be closed in order to deliver the data? How should I fix it?

Comment: This question is very confusing.   Also, it appears you're doing a sleep in a loop.  Surely there's a better approach using closures?  And I hope you're not trying to sleep the main thread.  Maybe that's why you have to "quit the simulator"?  Again, though, the question is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the server side i used `bufferedReader.readLine()` to read from the client. 
Though in the swift code client writes data to stream by `client.send("\(+1)")`. this do not attach new line character to the stream. So that Java server do not know data is fully came through or not because there is no new line character.

So `client.send("\(+1)\n")` is used. Now Server knows data is came through correctly. So that it prints the required output in the console.